# IE6 Float Drop

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I seem to have a bit of a problem with IE6, normally I would just drop the support for IE6 but the project I'm working on there is a chance that there will be lots of people visiting the site with IE6.
If you have IE6 and you want to check out the problem use my Home Page link.

Basically div#content drops below the div#left.
I tried [Robert Nyman](http://www.robertnyman.com/2007/11/13/stop-using-poor-performance-css-expressions-use-javascript-instead/) method but that didn't work.
Any body know any other method ?

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper{ width:980px; margin:auto; background-color:#fff }
#header{ width:980px; position:relative }
#middle{ width: 980px; padding:20px; overflow:hidden; clear:both }
#left{ float:left; width:200px }
#main{ width:740px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 210px }
#content { width: 480px; min-height: 400px; float:left }
#right{ float:left; width:240px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px }
#footer{ clear:both; width:980px; margin:auto; padding:20px 0 }
</style>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">

    </div>
    <div id="middle">
        <div id="left">

        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="content">

            </div>
            <div id="right">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see from the first look possible reasons (I even haven't dived into problem):

1) Always use DOCTYPE! Without it you'll never make crossbrowser normal-difficulty code.

2) For making such things try to use float properties more often!

3) I'm really surprised to see block with width: 980px; and padding: 20px; that should be placed in block with: width: 980px; Padding, included in width - is the past!!

4) #right has property: float: left; margin-left: 10px; - and IE6 makes margin-left = 20px in this case - it's very famous bug. Add to this block this property: display: inline; and it's gonna be ok (so, reason isn't in paddings, but in margins)

And don't forget to read standarts and recommendations!

Answer (score 0):

I added a `style="float: left; clear: none;"` to the content div, and that fixed it so that the middle div and the right div were on the same plane but both were pushed down the hight of the left div.

Why are you wrapping the content div and right div into a wrapper div but leaving the left div out? That's probably related.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a proper [doctype](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) so that the page is rendered in standards compliance mode. If it's rendered in quirks mode, IE uses a different box model which changes the size of most of your elemenents.

Is it the `main` or the `content` div that drops down? If it's the `main` div you could make it float left beside the `left` div.

You might have to adjust the size of the elements. Sometimes IE6 needs three extra pixels of space to fit elements in another element.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem!

I used a conditional statement and changed the padding from 20 to 10:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
    #middle{ width: 980px; padding:10px; overflow:hidden; clear:both; }
</style>
```